# Filter through nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

I have an array of objects and some keys contain a new array in there.

Now I want to return all objects that either have a certain value OR the nested array inside a property contains a certain value.

The array looks sth. like this:

```
const test = [
{
  test: 1,
  key: [{
    yes: true,
    no: null
  }]
}, 
{
  test: null,
  key: [{
    yes: true,
    no: null
  }]
}, 
{
  test: null,
  key: [{
    yes: null,
    no: null
  }]
}];
```

The solution I came up with, which doesn't work unfortunately was this:

`const filtered = test.filter(obj => obj.test || obj.key.filter(item => item.yes));`

So actually, only the first two objects should be returned, but it returns all three.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `.filter` returns an array; arrays are always true.

Comment: @melpomene thanks for the reply! but how can i filter for this nested array in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost brought it home. Use `obj.key.some` or `obj.filter().length > 0`
`Array.prototype.filter` will always return an array. It will be empty (`.length === 0`) when there was no item matching the predicate.

```js
const test = [{
    test: 1,
    key: [{
      yes: true,
      no: null
    }]
  },
  {
    test: null,
    key: [{
      yes: true,
      no: null
    }]
  },
  {
    test: null,
    key: [{
      yes: null,
      no: null
    }]
  }
];

const filtered = test.filter(obj => obj.test || obj.key.filter(item => item.yes).length > 0)

console.log(filtered)
```

The more "correct way" and "more performant way" is with using `Array.prototype.some` as it will internally quit the loop on the first "match", whereas `filter` will loop through every element in the array.

```
const predicate = obj => obj.test || obj.key.some(item => item.yes)

const filteres = test.filter(predicate)
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved it! Great to know about this in the future!

Answer (score 1):

You need to take [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), because this returns a boolean value instead of an array, which is even if empty, a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value.

```js
const
    test = [{ test: 1, key: [{ yes: true, no: null }] }, { test: null, key: [{ yes: true, no: null }] }, { test: null, key: [{ yes: null, no: null }] }],
    filtered = test.filter(obj => obj.test || obj.key.some(item => item.yes));
    
console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```